# Tooling API in production org

Tags: apex, deployment, tooling-api

I am already aware that you cannot directly create Apex classes in production orgs (have to use either the Force.com IDE or changesets). But if I include test cases can the Tooling API do it?

Also related question; can the Tooling API define Security Settings for classes/pages it creates as well?

Comment: I suspect this maybe possible providing you create a ApexClassMember for the two classes and utilise an MetadataContainer to deploy them together. I'll try and give this a go today and confirm. In the meantime, i have done this successfully with the Metadata API here, https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/blob/master/rolluptool/src/classes/RollupController.cls

Comment: I assume btw you want to do this from Apex, as such I'll be trying this out with the Apex Tooling API, https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi, do let me know if this is not what your after, but either way the steps will be the same in other languages.

Comment: I've added a confirmation comment to the answer you've received below, sadly the answer is no from the Tooling API.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies if this is not the most definitive or conclusive answer, however I notice on page 5 of the [Force.com Tooling API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf)
It states:

*Use create() to compile Apex classes or triggers in **Developer Edition or sandbox** organizations.*

This would suggest to me that it may not be possible to create APEX classes in production with the Tooling API- **but that is only my inference** it could just refer to the specific method - No doubt someone more knowledgeable on the subject would be able to clarify this.

Comment: But at the bottom of the guide for ApexExecutionOverlayAction it says: "Use ApexExecutionOverlayAction to overlay a diagnostic output on an Apex class or trigger without compromising production code." I'm not clear if this is the only class that works in production.

Comment: I can confirm this is indeed the case, the Tooling API can only be used to update or delete existing ApexClass's. The only way to create an ApexClass or ApexTrigger for that matter in a production org dynamically that i know is via the Salesforce Metadata API 'deploy' operation, as per this example, https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/blob/master/rolluptool/src/classes/RollupController.cls. It is unclear if the new Spring'14 Metadata API 'createMetadata' operation will support this (it's async version 'create' does not).