# Create Apex Trigger / Class using Python

Tags: apex, trigger, rest-api, metadata-api, python

I am trying to automate a few things for Salesforce using Python. I am using OAuth for Rest API for other processes like creating or updating records.

I need to figure out how to create Apex Trigger/Classes through API calls.
I have tried the below API and it works for development instance.

`https://[instance].salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger`

But I see this message in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apextrigger.htm).

> Although Apex classes and triggers have the Create and Update field properties, a runtime exception occurs if you try to create or update them using the API. Instead, use the Ant Migration Tool, the Salesforce user interface, or the Salesforce Extensions for Visual Studio Code to create or update Apex classes or triggers.

Is this warning applicable to the Production environment?
If so, then what method we can use which will work for both development & production using Python?

PS: I tried looking up Metadata API but it looks like Force WSC which is required for it is only available for Java. [Prerequisites Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_prereqs.htm)

> To run the samples, first download the latest force-wsc JAR file and its dependencies from mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-wsc/.

**Edit:**
[How do I use the Tooling API to create a new Apex Trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/how-do-i-use-the-tooling-api-to-create-a-new-apex-trigger)
 This question does not answer whether this will work in production instance or not.
[Tooling API in production org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32016/tooling-api-in-production-org) suggests that it will not.

Comment: I had looked at this but I am not sure if this will work for a production instance.

Comment: @identigral https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32016/tooling-api-in-production-org suggests that creating Apex class will not work with Tooling API for production.

Comment: Correct, it will not work in Production. If you need to automate the entire process, you can deploy the trigger + required unit tests via Tooling to sandbox, then create change set in the sandbox and deploy the change set to Production via Metadata API